# Querying anonymous classes in OWL API with Manchester Syntax

Tags: ontology, owl, protege, owl-api, manchester-syntax

I'm using OWL API for reasoning over ontology created in Protege. I'm dealing with OWL API Example DL query: http://sourceforge.net/p/owlapi/code/ci/aef6981535f07a2d0d44c394b9f4d5415f36025a/tree/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/DLQueryExample.java. I guess that this example provides functionality equivalent to DL Query Tab in Protege. But in fact there are some significant differences: I need to get the information (subclass, superclass, etc.) of an anonymous class, which is defined by a set of individuals (ex {Member1, Member2...}) or in another way. In Protege this query returns correct result, but such query in OWL API Dl Query Example returns [NOTHING]. Is there a way to manipulate anonymous classes in OWL API? Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: The `DLQueryExample` should handle anonymous class expressions as input (just like in Protege). Could you precise the exact expression you've used as well as including a snippet or link to the ontology you're using?

Comment: @loopasam, thanks for the answer. I tried on the Pizza sample: http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl. The query is simple: Pizza and (hasTopping some CheeseTopping), the result is: Loaded ontology: OntologyID(OntologyIRI(<http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/
pizza.owl>))
Please type a class expression in Manchester Syntax and press Enter (or press x
to exit):
Pizza and (hasTopping some CheeseTopping)
QUERY:   Pizza and (hasTopping some CheeseTopping)
SuperClasses
        [NONE]
EquivalentClasses
        [NONE]
SubClasses
        [NONE]
Instances
        [NONE]

Comment: Link to the problematic DL query example is now: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version3/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/DLQueryExample.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using [the class](http://sourceforge.net/p/owlapi/code/ci/aef6981535f07a2d0d44c394b9f4d5415f36025a/tree/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/DLQueryExample.java) `DLQueryExample` as such without modifications.

You need to use a different reasoner than the default one. Look at line 151, the implementation uses the structural reasoner built in the OWL-API. This reasoner is limited and not capable of processing complex class expressions as yours.

How to fix it:

Use a more advanced reasoner like [Hermit](http://hermit-reasoner.com/). Download and put the jar on your classpath, then replace the code at line 151 by that:

`OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new Reasoner.ReasonerFactory();`

You will need to import the package `org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner`. You will now use Hermit to process your queries. Try `Pizza and (hasTopping some CheeseTopping)`, it should work!

Comment: OWL API now provides a documentation regarding this problem: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/DL-Queries-with-a-real-reasoner